# ReadString method of XmlReader removes/ignore CDATA tag

Tags: xml, xmlreader

I'm getting a very strange behavior and unable to identify the issue. In following code snippet expected out was

```
<![CDATA[<air:FareInfo Key="10T"></air:FareInfo>/>]]>
```

but I'm getting

```
<air:FareInfo Key="10T"></air:FareInfo>/>
```

why CDATA tag is missing in output? I'm simply using XmlReader.ReadString() and it ignores CDATA tag.

```
 string xml = "<FareInfo>" + 
        "<![CDATA[<air:FareInfo Key=\"10T\">" + 
            "</air:FareInfo>/>]]>" + 
        "</FareInfo>";

        Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(xml);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

        reader.Read();

        string output = reader.ReadString();

        Console.Write(output);
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
 switch (reader.NodeType) {
      case XmlNodeType.Text:
          Console.Write(reader.Value);
          break;
       case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
           Console.Write("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", reader.Value);
           break;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Siva. I was thinking on the same lines. Would u please do let me know why Readstring() ignore CDATA?

Comment: In XML "![CDATA" is a special tag similar to "<" or ">". XmlReader ignores it in the same way as it ignores "<" or ">".